# when piped with ls, grep command is not working in solaris

Tags: linux, unix, grep, solaris, ls

I am using the below command in solaris

```
ls -l | grep '*PROC*'
```

But it is not working. I have many files that contain "PROC" in their name like XREF_PROC.complete but when I use the above command its not showing any output. When I use `ls *PROC*` its working but not working with grep.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you wrote is "get all lines containing `*` character, then containing `PRO` string and zero or more `C` letters.
Try this

```
ls -l | grep PROC
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I use REDHAT unix servers and when I do `ls -l | grep *PROC*` it works fine. But not in solaris. So is this a unique case in solaris or am I missing somethinh

Comment: No, `greo *PROC*` will never work. This is because `*` will be expanded as a glob expression by your shell.

Comment: @hek2mgl There is a case where `grep *PROC*` will work.

Answer (score 3):

You are running different commands in Linux and Solaris.

The following won't work as nsilent22 already stated, this is regardless of the OS:

```
ls -l | grep '*PROC*'
```

It would have worked in the unlikely event the files have a `*` character in their name preceding `PRO`.

The following one will work (sort of) if `*PROC*` expands only once, i.e. if there is only one file with PROC in its own name:

```
ls -l | grep *PROC*
```

This can also explain the difference in behavior you might have observed between Solaris and Linux but is actually unrelated of the OS. You tell there are many files with PROC in their names under Solaris but there might have been just one under Linux.

In any case, using `grep` here is mostly useless except in the very specific case there are too much files matching `*PROC*` in the directory for their names to fit the environment. Otherwise, you would have the expected result with this simpler command:

```
ls -l *PROC*
```

Comment: Good catch! *But actually unrelated to the OS* - you are right!

Answer (score 1):

Never pipe ls outputs to grep. Use `find` instead:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -name '*POC*'
```

However, just for explanation. The basic problem with the above statement is the regular expression, it should be `grep 'PROC'` instead.

Comment: @sandywho - you might have used  `ls -ltr *PROC*` to list the files that contains PROC in their file names. The behavior of "*" will be different with grep.